# Converting to parquet file format while load to hive tables

Tags: mysql, hadoop

We want to do real time replication from mysql to hdfs with the files being stored as the parquet format in the hdfs cluster.

As for as we know ,we can do this using either

1)tungsten replicator or
2)Mysql server supports live replication to hdfs.

But our problem is that none of them support conversion to parquet while loading data to hdfs.

so just wanted to know whether is there any way to do real time replication with the file being stored as parquet in hdfs cluster.

Second question is that when you load csv file in hive tables using "LOAD DATA INPATH" and if the table has been define as Parquet file format ,will hive convert the file to parquet format or we need to write a utility to convert the file to parquet format and then load.

Answer (score 0):

Second question : The  CREATE TABLE statement should specify the Parquet storage format with syntax.
it all boils down to the version of Hive . some version do not support parquet file